# Is a sequence necessary in MySQL connection-string?

Tags: mysql, .net, connector-net

I am using connector/net but sometimes a connection error is generated on the server due to connection-string.

Is there any sequence to follow?

```
connection_string conn = new connection-string("User ID=root;Password=myPassword;
Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;
Direct=true;Protocol=TCP;Compress=false;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;
Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;");
```

Comment: Which language is this? What connection error is generated?

Comment: this part would be written on application side in .net language.